# Actionbar spinner dropdown is showing on top of the spinner for devices below 1080p resolution

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner, android-actionbar-compat

Hi I have a spinner on actionbar. When running the app on the devices below 1080p resolution, the spinner dropdown is showing on top of the spinner. 
Like in the pic:

[image]

It is working fine on the devices with 1080p resolution, but not on the devices below 1080p resolution.

Getting the device's display width through displaymetrics and setting

```
    spinner.setDropDownVerticalOffset(value);
```

according to that will fix the issue but it requires API level 16. My app's min sdk is 9 target sdk 21` .

This is the code that I've used for spinner:

```
     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerJ"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sub_heading_font_size" />
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance! :)